# What is the difference in the two JVM Kotlin "create project" options in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Using [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) Community Edition 2017.1, I am presented with two ways to create a [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) project for the JVM:

- File->New->Project->Java->Kotlin (Java)
- File->New->Project->Kotlin->Kotlin(JVM)

Is there a difference between what each does, and if so, what is it?
(The IntelliJ Idea Kotlin "tutorial" [uses the first method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started.html))

[image: IntelliJ Java - Kotlin project dialog]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two options. The two paths exist because people can think of their project as either a Java project with Kotlin, or as a Kotlin project.

Comment: I had results that matched a previous answer - one gave you the runtime by default in the project file, the other didn't. But just now I got the runtime with both?? I am going to have to ask another question on how to not get the runtime as it isn't clear to me.

Comment: If you don't need a runtime, simply create a Java project and don't select any Kotlin options.